# Modify the Jackson Annotation from xml

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jackson

I am using Jackson library in my project.

I am having a list data type like below

```
List<String> Names;
```

The output is produced is:

```
<Names>
<Names>bob</Names>
<Names>ram</Names>
</Names>
```

But I Expect the output to be like this :

```
<Names>
<Name>bob</Name>
<Name>ram</Name>
</Names>
```

I have used `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper` and  `@JacksonXmlElement`, is there any generic way of doing this because i have huge list in my program.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Following this two you can make the list like

```
 1. @JacksonXmlElementWrapper
 2. @JacksonXmlElement
```

Expected Output :

```
<Names>
<Name>bob</Name>
<Name>ram</Name>
</Names>
```

There is no other external thing given by Jackson for doing this.